# How to delete the values which are not followed by second immediate cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How to delete the values which are not followed by second immediate cell?

[image: How to delete the values in Cell A which are not followed by the values in cell B]

Comment: Followd by **the values** or **a value in B**?

Comment: Followed by values

Comment: Which cells should be deleted in your example ?

Comment: A screen shot is attached, I want to delete those values which are in column A but are not followed by the values in column B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following might help.

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim cel As Range

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet5")  'change Sheet5 to your data sheet
    With ws
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For Each cel In .Range("B1:B" & lastRow)
            If IsEmpty(cel) Then    'or use If Len(cel) = 0 Then
                cel.Offset(0, -1).ClearContents
            End If
        Next cel
    End With
End Sub
```

If you want to delete the rows where `Column B` is empty then try this

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet5")  'change Sheet5 to your data sheet
    ws.Range("B1:B100").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete 'change range as per your data
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this macro. Enter it in regular module (eq Module 1). it will remove all values in column `A` in case there is no value in adjacent cell in column `B`.

```
Sub delete()
For x = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    If Range("B" & x).Value <> "" Then
    Else
       Range("A" & x).ClearContents
    End If
Next x
End Sub
```

or if you want to delete those rows.

```
Sub deleteRows()
For x = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
    If Range("B" & x).Value <> "" Then
    Else
       Range("A" & x).EntireRow.delete
    End If
Next x
End Sub
```